# Understanding risks of @uncheckedVariance in method argument

Tags: scala, generics, generic-programming

I don't success to figure out how following example can be risky.

To be more specific to my case, the `exFrom` method is `protected` and called by other methods  giving to it exactly an object of type `X`. In that situation i don't figure out how it can be dangerous but i'm not confident enough about it.

```
trait A { val a: Int }

case class B(val a: Int) extends A

case class C(val a: Int) extends A

case class Toto[+X <: A](val x: X) {

    def exFrom(in: X @uncheckedVariance): Toto[X] = Toto(in)

    protected def protectedFrom(in: X @uncheckedVariance): Toto[X] = Toto(in)

    // Is using protectedFrom in situation like in f is risky ? 
    def f: Toto[X] = protectedFrom(ops(x): X)

}

object TestToto {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val t: Toto[B] = Toto(B(1))
        val ta: Toto[A] = t // Works thanks to covariance on X

        ta.exFrom(B(2)) // Works
        ta.exFrom(C(2)) // Works

        // Do you have example of how it can failed ?

    }

}
```

Comment: It would be good to include a minimal definition of `ops` since at this point I do not see the point of `exFrom`

Comment: ops is supposed to be any operation taking a `X` and outputing a `X`, it could be indentity.

Comment: So why you need the upcast? In any case, what is even the point of `protectedFrom` or `exFrom` or whatever, why not just `Toto(f(x))`?

Comment: Because in reality Toto is not a case class but a trait, and the goal is to not rewritte methods as f and others in each Toto descendant, declaring them only once in first trait.

Comment: Ah, so you basically want to access the constructor of each subclass. Then yes, this should be fine. Although, maybe, you may want to consider changing this subtyping pattern to other forms of polymorphism like **pattern matching** or a **typeclass**, those may be better _(or worse)_ alternative for your problem; without more details is hard to tell but I guess you can check those alternatives and decide by yourself.

Comment: Pattern matching will works fine if i know in advance the whole classes, but it is not the case, i will investigate the typeclass way. But if you say it will be fine why compiler complains me about wrong variance, i know it is a contravariant position but i don't want to do fancy stuff other than shown. Thanks